# Java Map interface, method remove takes object

Tags: java, collections

I have the following code snippet:

```
Set<Short> map=new HashSet<>();
short i=1;
map.add(i);
map.remove(i-1)
```

It ignores removal because I-1 was automatically casted to integer. But, why there is no remove(V) method with generic? It's bad, I should see an exception or this method should be generic. Doesn't make any sense. Why was it designed this way?

**The question is:**

If we have Set, why don't we have method remove(E e) inside it? I found that it's because internally there is an array of Object. But why? If we have Set  of E generic type, why don't we have E[] as internal storage? For me it's absolutely doesn't make sense.

For example I expected:

```
class Set<E>{
   private E[] values;

   public void add(E e);

   public void remove(E e);

}
```

But I got:

```
class Set<E>{
   private Object[] values;

   public void add(E e);

   public void remove(Object e);

}
```

Why not to do this?

```
class Set<E>{
   private E[] values;

   public void add(E e);

   public void remove(E e){ 
      for(E v:values){
         if(v.equals(e)){
            //remove element
         }
      }
    }
}
```

????

Comment: You might want to post code the compiles. Map has no add method. Perhaps you meant List.

Comment: Your question isn't clear...

Comment: Thanks, sorry I meant set

Comment: You can try to remove an Object which is not there.

Comment: It's logically that there's no any object of other type than E, so it even should not try to delete object of wrong type

Comment: one reason is, that the `Collection#remove` method relies on `Object` equality. This equality is defined by `Object#equals(Object)` which doesn´t neccessarly needs to identify two of the same classes as equal. A `String` could potentionally be equal to an instance of `Employee` if the `Employee` class defines it like this in it´s overriden equal method. The remove method just catches on on this. Also the remove method isn´t bound to work with a correct type, whilst on the other hand the `Collection#add` method would potentionally create exceptions when working with a different type.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not make sense either. All objects extends Object class.And there in equals method defined. What the problem?

Comment: See updated post. Thanks